# showing different textboxes on same page according to the selection of values from dropdownlist using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with  dropdownbox with 2 values,and if I select one value I should get three textboxes and if I SELECT OTHER VALUE i Should get different textbox.how to do this by using javascript?

Please help me ...

Regards,
Dhanya Raj

Comment: what you have tried so far please paste some of your efforts or make fiddle or snippet to figure out others where you stucked?

Comment: You should write some code, then ask here when you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function select_value(valueSelect)
{
    if(valueSelect){
        value1 = document.getElementById("one").value;
        value2 = document.getElementById("two").value;
        if(value1 == valueSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("three_text_boxes").style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById("one_text_box").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if(value2 == valueSelect.value) {
            document.getElementById("one_text_box").style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById("three_text_boxes").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

```css
#three_text_boxes , #one_text_box{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select  onchange="select_value(this);">
<option id="zero" value="0">None</option>
<option id ="one" value="1">one</option>
<option id="two" value="2">two</option>
</select>


<div id="three_text_boxes" >
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
 </div>
 
 <div id="one_text_box" >
<input type="text">
 </div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: :Thanks Bhavin,it is working but now when I select the page I have given one value as default and it should show only that vlue's text boxes,but now I'm getting both values textboxes when I select the page and If I select the other value seperately,then it is fine..Please help me to change it like when I select that page only default value and its textboxes should appear..

Comment: sorry but i didn't get you. can you provide your working code so that it can be more helpful to me to solve your problem.?